# Not showing data array

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why when it gets gets to the getLast5Messages function in my controller it returns the following but in the response in the javascript it puts the html of the page. I don't get it.

```
[{"id":"1","subject":"Testing","firstName":"Kevin","lastName":"Smith","dateSent":"March 30th, 2012","messageRead":"0"}]
```

js:

```
function getMessages()
{
$('.mail').empty();
$.get('dashboard/getLast5Messages', function(data)
{
   if(data.length > 0)
    {
        $.each(data, function(x)
        {
            if (data[x]['messageRead'] == 0) 
            {
                $('.mail').append('<li><a href="pmsystem/viewmessage/'+data[x]['id']+'"><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>'); 
            }
            else
            {
                $('.mail').append('<li class="read"><a href="pmsystem/viewmessage/'+data[x]['id']+'"><strong>Received: '+data[x]['dateSent']+'</strong><small>'+data[x]['subject']+'</small><small>From: '+data[x]['firstName']+' '+data[x]['lastName']+'</small></a></li>');     
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.mail').append('<li>No Messages</li>');
    }
}, 'json');
}
```

php:

```
public function getLast5Messages()
{
    echo $this->pmmodel->getLast5Messages($this->session->userdata('userID'));
}

/**
 * Retrieve last 5 messages in inbox
 *
 * @param   integer
 * @return  object
 */
function getLast5Messages($userID)
{
    // Check args
    if (!is_numeric($userID))
    {
        throw new Exception('Non-numeric $userID provided to getLast5Messages()');
    }

    $this->db->select('pm.id');
    $this->db->select('pm.subject');
    $this->db->select('users.firstName');
    $this->db->select('users.lastName');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(pm.dateSent, '%M %D, %Y') AS dateSent", false);
    $this->db->select('pmr.messageRead');
    $this->db->from('usersPersonalMessages AS pm');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.userID = pm.senderID');
    $this->db->join('usersPersonalMessagesRecipients AS pmr',
        'pm.id = pmr.usersPersonalMessagesID');
    $this->db->where('pmr.userID', $userID);
    $this->db->order_by('pm.dateSent', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return array();
}
```

I'm still not able to figure this out? Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean " response in the javascript it puts the html of the page"? Can you express your issue more clearly?

Comment: Look at the XHR request in your developer console to see what exactly is being returned from the server. Seems like your `getLast5Messages()` PHP function may be wrapped in an HTML document.

Comment: Its not though. http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/dashboard/getLast5Messages

Comment: Just got an error on your page.  Make sure when you are done with testing and active development, that you turn the error reporting off to the browser.

Comment: If I do console.log(data); inside the get function I get "Array"

Comment: You can't echo an array. Try [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: I've tried that and it produced the same thing.

Comment: Wow that was odd now it wants to freaking work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was

```
public function getLast5Messages()
{
    echo json_encode($this->pmmodel->getLast5Messages($this->session->userdata('userID')));
}
```